# FileTransfer plugin, download not starting on iOS, no errors on callbacks

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, ionic3, file-transfer, ionic-native

I’m trying to create an Ionic 3 App that downloads an image from internet and stores it in the device file system.
On an Android device all is working fine, on iOS the call to FileTransferObject.download(…) seems to hang doing nothing; I get no error callback and nothing is downloaded.
I created a sample repo you can check out at: https://github.com/andreabarani/TestFileTransferPlugin
You will find 2 branches in it:

- ‘**master**’ using version 1.6.3 of the plugin
- ‘**file-transfer-plugin-1.7.0**’ using version 1.7.0

Both versions produce same results on iOS while 1.7.0 makes Android build fail.

Any help is very appreciated, tnx in advance
Andrea

Comment: Not really helpful but I've got 2 notes; 1. I use v1.6.3, recently had problems building my application with v1.7.0 either. 2. Wrap your plugin methods within a platform.ready() statement.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby: tnx for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't solve

Comment: @JoeriShoeby: Now that I solved the problem I think that your suggestion was right, because I wrapped in a "platform.ready()" statement all the calls to the plugin, but not the creation of the instance of the plugin itself. So tnx again

Comment: Great I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: my mistake was creating the FileTransferObject too soon, probably when platform wasn't yet ready; my code was like this:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      providers: [FileTransfer, File]
    })
    export class HomePage {
      private fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create(); // <-- here is too soon to create it
    ...
```

This is instead the right way of doing it:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      providers: [FileTransfer, File]
    })
    export class HomePage {
      private fileTransfer: FileTransferObject;
      ...
      ...

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private platform: Platform) {
      }

      downloadFile() {
        // using a local constant is also a valid alternative,
        // the important thing is to instantiate the object at this time
        // const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
```

Regarding Android compilation problems with version 1.7.0 of the FileTransfer plugin, all was solved by updating Android Studio to version 3.0.1 from 2.3.3.

The complete working app is available here: https://github.com/andreabarani/TestFileTransferPlugin